# List of native/built-in T-SQL functions that use CLR functions? (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, clr

I would like to find a list of native/built-in T-SQL functions and stored procedures (i.e. programmability) in SQL Server 2008 R2 which use CLR under the hood.

For example, I know that [STDistance()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933952(v=sql.105).aspx) and other spatial-related stuff like [geometry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487(v=sql.105).aspx) and [geography](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766(v=sql.105).aspx) are implemented in CLR but I'd like to find a complete list.

Anyone know where I can find such a list?

Comment: I don't think they're documented in that way anywhere, and I'm not sure there are many in 2008 R2 anyway. `FORMAT()` in 2012 is certainly one that comes to mind, and probably `PARSE()`, `TRY_PARSE()`, `TRY_CONVERT()`, etc.

Comment: What would you do differently from now if you actually had this list available to you?

Comment: @Damien, I am troubleshooting SQL Server memory pressure which appears to be clearly attributable to the use of the CLR. I know the app uses spatial functions but I'd like to search the app's codebase for other CLR functions.